# variable in array (php)

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add random description to the game. Game description must contain a game title like this

```
'1' => 'some text1 (game_title) some text'
```

After that, new description send to database.
Here is my code.

```
        $game_descr = array('1' => 'some text1 (post_title) some text' ,
                        '2' => 'some text2 (post_title) some text' ,
                        '3' => 'some text3 (post_title) some text' ,
                        '4' => 'some text4 (post_title) some text' ,
                        '5' => 'some text5 (post_title) some text' ,
                        '6' => 'some text6 (post_title) some text' ,
                        '7' => 'some text7 (post_title) some text' ,
                        '8' => 'some text8 (post_title) some text' ,
                        '9' => 'some text9 (post_title) some text' ,
    );


    $newtable = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title, post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'");
    foreach ($newtable as $gametable) {
            foreach ($game_descr as $i => $value) {
                $rand_value = rand(1,9);
            }
    echo '<div class="game_descr"><textarea name="game_descr">'.$game_descr[$rand_value].'<br />'.$gametable->post_content.'</textarea></div>';
    }
```

I do not publis database updating code, becouse it work)
So, how to add game title to the description?

Comment: Is there any relation between `post_title` in your `$game_descr` and the `post_title` in your query? Is the value from the query supposed to replace the value in the array?

Comment: Why are you doing a `foreach()` loop -  `foreach ($game_descr as $i => $value)` - inside the `foreach()` loop from your query? You are basically overwriting `$rand_value` 8 times, and only getting the last value. Just do the `$rand_value = rand(1,9);` without the `foreach()` that is wrapping it.

Comment: $game_descr contain templates of derscription. game_title value from the query replace the game_title value in the array

Comment: becouse, i newbie in php). Thanks, i'll fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php), use `%s` as placeholder:

```
$game_descr = [
  1 => 'some text1 (%s) some text',
  // ...
];

$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title, post_content
  FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'");
foreach ($posts as $p) {
  $index = mt_rand(1, count($game_descr));
  $descr = sprintf($game_descr[$index], $p->post_content);

  echo <<<EOS
<div class="game_descr">
  <textarea name="game_descr">{$descr}<br/>
  {$p->post_content}
  </textarea>
</div>;
EOS;
}
```

Comment: if i need use ($s) more than 1 time, i need add this $descr = sprintf($game_descr[$index], $p->post_content, $p->post_content); right?

Comment: @skit008, adjust the format string accordingly, e.g.: `sprintf("%s ... %s", $one, $two);`